# Table cell borders not aligning when using colspan

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align two HTML tables, one underneath the other. The reason for this is that I need two headers, and they both need to remain fixed when the user scrolls. I'm using [jQuery floatThead](http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/) to achieve this but it only floats a single `thead` row. My workaround is something like:

```
<div>
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <thead>
           <tr>
               <th colspan="2" style="width:50%;">Etc</th>
               <th colspan="2" style="width:50%;">Etc</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="floatTheadContainer">
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <thead>
           <tr>
               <th style="width:25%;">Etc</th>
               <th style="width:25%;">Etc</th>
               <th style="width:25%;">Etc</th>
               <th style="width:25%;">Etc</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

The more realistic example is at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/szg9mm61/3/) - the cell borders don't align even though the width percentages are equal

Answer (score 0):

You have `<th style="width:2%;"></th>`, which adds the extra box. I'm assuming that's what you wanted. Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/szg9mm61/4/).

Comment: or is it the top row? Where the blank space and etc's are uneven?

Comment: The borders of both the rows' cells don't align, I need them to align

Comment: I still don't understand... What do you want it to look like? An example?